# Add boundry from current location in google map android

Tags: android, google-maps

i am developing application using google maps i am successfully get current location but i am unable to directly go to my location .i want to go to my current location when open my app and add some circle from that location please tell me how it is

my code

```
  public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    GoogleMap _googleMap;

    LatLng myPosition;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        _googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment)        
                 getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                R.id.map)).getMap(); 
        if(_googleMap==null){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Google Map Not Available",          
                       Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            LocationManager locationManger = 
                       (LocationManager)getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
            Criteria criteria=new Criteria();
            String provider = locationManger.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
            Location location = locationManger.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
            if(location!=null){
                double latitude = location.getLatitude();
                double langitude = location.getLongitude();
                LatLng latlang = new LatLng(latitude, langitude);
                LatLngBounds curScreen = 
                               _googleMap.getProjection().getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds;
                curScreen.contains(latlang);
                myPosition = new LatLng(latitude, langitude);

                _googleMap.addMarker(new 
                          MarkerOptions().position(myPosition).title("start"));


            }
                }
```

Comment: add this  _googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(myPosition));

Comment: you have to call  **_googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(myPosition));** in your code. And circle means radius. Isn't it?

Comment: ya radius from my loaction